# Is it possible to have a Datatables search box search one column, but use dropdowns for others?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to design a [Datatables](http://datatables.net) table to meet a specific set of criteria.

1. There will be column dropdowns, so that if an option is selected it will show only columns that match that value in its entirety.
2. There will be a search box, and typingin this will filter *on the first column only*.

Unfortunately, it seems like these are two contradictory requirements in DataTables.

This code, allows be to restrict the search bar to the first column,

```
numCols = $("#myTable thead tr:first th").length
columns = [{ "searchable": true }]
for (var i=1; i < numCols; i++) {
    columns.push({ "searchable": false });
}

var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "columns":columns
});
```

But, when using [`column.search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) this code:

```
$("#myTable thead tr:first th").each( function ( i ) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("filter")) {
        var select = $('<select name="select_column_'+i+'"><option value="">ALL</option></select>')
        .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
        .on( 'change', function () {
            table.column(i)
            .search( $(this).val(),false,false,false)
            .draw();
        } );

        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d.replace(/[[\]\/()]/g,'\\$&')+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        });
    }
});
```

Now, I know I've set `searchable` to false in the `columns` declaration of the table, and removing this allows the dropdowns to work again - but it means that the search text box the filters the table on *all* columns, not just the first.

The legacy documentation says there was a `bFilterable` option that did a simialr thing, but this is no longer in the current release. And now I'm all out of ideas.

**So, is there a way to restrict a Datatables table such that the search box filters on only one column, while allowing dropdown based filtering on on others?**

PS: [For the curious, here is jsFiddle that shows the problem pretty clearly.](http://jsfiddle.net/s3bL3ty1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, this isn't possible using the standard Datatables API, but using jQuery the table can be extended to manage this.

First of all, leave searching on for every column that will be searched (so exclude any `searching` options on the columns.

Then turn of the filtering box using the [`DataTables.dom` option](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) by removing the `f` flag.

Then create a custom search box prior to the table itself:

```
$('<input type="text" />')
    .insertBefore('#myTable')
    .before('<label>My special search: </label>')
    .on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
        .column( 0 )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
    });
```

This applies the search just to column 0. However the line

```
.column( 0 )
```

can be changed to match rows were the strings in in any arbitrary columns like so:

```
.columns(0,1,2)
```

or can be made to match rows where search string is in *all* of the given columns like so:

```
.column([0,1,2])
```

There are number of fiddles that demo this, so you can see

- [matching just the first column](http://jsfiddle.net/n75Ltx9c/2/),
- [matching a string in *any* of the first 3 columns](http://jsfiddle.net/n75Ltx9c/3/) or
- [matching a string across *all* of the first three columns](http://jsfiddle.net/n75Ltx9c/1/).

The best example string to see the difference in functionality is `an`.